# How do you programmatically update an email vacation response using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script for the first time and am trying to simply update my vacation response in Gmail programmatically as a first test of Google Apps Script.

I'm following the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateVacation

And I have written:

```
function updateAutoResponse(){
    Gmail.Users.Settings.updateVacation('me', {
        "enableAutoReply": true,
        "responseSubject": "I am not here...",
        "responseBodyPlainText": "I am not here...",
        "responseBodyHtml": "I am not here...",
        "restrictToContacts": false,
        "restrictToDomain": false       
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an error after it appears to compile.  Parse Error (line 65, file "Code")

I've enabled the Gmail API in Advanced Google Services as well as in the Google API Console, so I think this is a syntax issue somewhere.

Any thoughts would be super helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

this is a simple fix:

```
function updateAutoResponse(){
    Gmail.Users.Settings.updateVacation(
      {
        "enableAutoReply": true,
        "responseSubject": "Test",
        "responseBodyHtml": "Testing script, not actually gone",
        "restrictToContacts": false,
        "restrictToDomain": false
      },
      'me'
    );
}
```

The `userId` is the second argument, not the first. It's not written in the documentation, however if you allow Apps Script autocomplete to show you the syntax, it states `updateVacation(VacationSettings resource, String userId) : VacationSettings`.

Also, not sure if this has any impact, but I am pretty sure there is no point in providing both `responseBodyHtml` and `responseBodyPlainText` seeing as they fill the exact same spot. If you don't need the HTML, you can just use PlainText, but if you want formatting, you use HTML and PlainText will be used whenever the recipient does not accept HTML (formatting will just get removed)